# Calculate the difference between all values in a group and a reference value for the group in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                  Var1 = c(23, 41, 32, 58, 60,12,34,55,49,60,64),
                  Var2 = c(4,5,2,1,7,3,4,5,5,6,9))
   ID Var1 Var2
1   1   23    4
2   1   41    5
3   1   32    2
4   1   58    1
5   1   60    7
6   2   12    3
7   2   34    4
8   2   55    5
9   2   49    5
10  2   60    6
11  2   64    9
```

and another one like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2),
                  Var1 = c(20,67),
                  Var2 = c(5,3))

  ID Var1 Var2
1  1   20    5
2  2   67    3
```

I want to add a column to the first dataframe with the absolute difference between the columns of the two dataframes for every `ID` group. That is 20 (i.e., the `Var1` value with `ID` equal to `1` in the second dataframe) should be subtracted from every `Var1` value with an `ID` equal to `1` in the first dataframe and then the absolute value should be given in an added column.

I figured out one solution which is rather cumbersome as I have a much larger dataframe with many variables:
First, I would merge the two dataframes by the `ID` column and then add another column calculating the absolute difference:

```
df3 <- merge(df1,df2,by="ID")
df3$Var1_Diff <- abs(df3$Var1.x - df3$Var1.y)
print(df3)
```

So that I end up with a ugly dataframe like this:

```
       ID Var1.x Var2.x Var1.y Var2.y Var1_Diff
1   1     23      4     20      5         3
2   1     41      5     20      5        21
3   1     32      2     20      5        12
4   1     58      1     20      5        38
5   1     60      7     20      5        40
6   2     12      3     67      3        55
7   2     34      4     67      3        33
8   2     55      5     67      3        12
9   2     49      5     67      3        18
10  2     60      6     67      3         7
11  2     64      9     67      3         3
```

Can anyone suggest a simpler solution where I just add a column to the first dataframe?

Also, as I have do this process for many `Var` colums it would be awesome if the solution could also take that into consideration.

Thank you!

Comment: try ```df1$Var1_Diff <- abs(df1$Var1-df2$Var1[match(df1$ID,df2$ID)])```

Comment: Extending @one's suggestion to multiple columns: `cols <- startsWith(names(df1), "Var"); cbind(df1, setNames(abs(df1[,cols] - df2[match(df1$ID, df2$ID), cols]), paste0(names(df1)[cols], "_diff")))`

Comment: @jblood94 Thank you again! I like this one the best I think as it is very easy to understand :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should scale up nicely:

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(list(keep = df1, ref = df2), .id = "source") |>
  mutate(
    across(starts_with("Var"), \(x) abs(x - x[source == "ref"]),
           .names = "{.col}_diff"),
    .by = ID
  ) |>
  filter(source == "keep") |>
  select(-source)
#    ID Var1 Var2 Var1_diff Var2_diff
# 1   1   23    4         3         1
# 2   1   41    5        21         0
# 3   1   32    2        12         3
# 4   1   58    1        38         4
# 5   1   60    7        40         2
# 6   2   12    3        55         0
# 7   2   34    4        33         1
# 8   2   55    5        12         2
# 9   2   49    5        18         2
# 10  2   60    6         7         3
# 11  2   64    9         3         6
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for! Can I somehow leave out the `starts_with("Var") ` part as in my original dataset the variables have actual names? It would be ideal if it would just take the name of the column and then add the `_diff` as you did.

Comment: Yes, you can replace `starts_with("Var")` with `c(Var1, Var2)` or a series of columns with `Var1:Var2` or any other select helper (see `?starts_with` for other options).

Answer (score 1):

You can skip some of the intermediates with a `data.table` join:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df1)[
  setDT(df2),
  `:=`(diff1 = abs(i.Var1 - Var1), diff2 = abs(i.Var2 - Var2)),
  on = "ID"
][]
#>     ID Var1 Var2 diff1 diff2
#>  1:  1   23    4     3     1
#>  2:  1   41    5    21     0
#>  3:  1   32    2    12     3
#>  4:  1   58    1    38     4
#>  5:  1   60    7    40     2
#>  6:  2   12    3    55     0
#>  7:  2   34    4    33     1
#>  8:  2   55    5    12     2
#>  9:  2   49    5    18     2
#> 10:  2   60    6     7     3
#> 11:  2   64    9     3     6
```

Comment: Thank you for your great solution! I think I prefer the one by GregorThomas as then I do not have to write out the difference for every variable :)